# Remove a:hover on a media stylesheet?

Tags: css, media-queries

How can I delete a style entry stated in the main CSS-file in a media query CSS-file?

For example, I'd like to delete the a:hover entry for use on touch devices.

main.css: `a:hover {color:#999999; background:#111111;}`

How can I cancel this out in the media.css?

Comment: You can not delete CSS rules, you can just overwrite them. So you could either set color and background to the not-hovered values in media.css or you include `a:hover {color:#999999; background:#111111;}` in a special desktop.css and not in main.css

Comment: What's your media query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't "delete" CSS rules.<sup>1</sup> The cascade doesn't work that way.

The only way to get your rule to apply only when the media query isn't satisfied is to isolate it in a negated version of the query, either in a `@media` block within your main.css stylesheet:

```
@media not [your media query] {
    a:hover {color:#999999; background:#111111;}
}
```

Or in a separate stylesheet within your page head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="[your media query]" href="media.css">

<!-- Or put this in a separate file and link to it as above -->
<style media="not [your media query]">
a:hover {color:#999999; background:#111111;}
</style>
```

Alternatively you can undo the styles within your media.css stylesheet, but the downside to that is you must know what values to fall back to.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Except in a desktop browser's developer tools, maybe.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I'll undo the styles then. I just thought there was a fancy way of doing that without writing too much code.

Answer (score 0):

your options are specificity or importants. or simply add the media query stylesheet after the main style sheet if they have the same specificity.

Answer (score 0):

The best option that I found was to use a media query to set the hover states in the first place

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px){
  a:hover {color:#999999; background:#111111;}
}
```

Using "min-width" allows you to have hover states on desktop but as soon as the screen goes below 800px (or whatever your breakpoint is) all hover states are disabled and you can set the styles exactly how you want from there.